# JNA code working fine in OSx , but unable to lookup function in Linux from C shared object file

Tags: java, c, jna

I am working with the following example: https://github.com/caplin/jnijnaexamples/tree/master/jna

**In mac**, I could create the .dylib file as follows:

> gcc -shared -fpic -o librandomjna.o randomjna.c
>
> g++ -dynamiclib -undefined suppress -flat_namespace *.o -o librandomjna.dylib
>
> mkdir classes
>
> javac -d classes -classpath jna-4.4.0.jar JavaNativeAccess.java
>
> cd classes
>
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
>
> java -classpath jna-4.4.0.jar:. com.enlightedinc.apps.where.utils.JavaNativeAccess

### In OSx, it works as expected and able to execute the C function list_files

**Now in Linux Box**, I created the .so file as follows

> gcc -shared -fpic -o librandomjna.o randomjna.c
>
> gcc -shared -o librandomjna.so *.o
>
> In the same way, new classes are generated in Linux mkdir classes
>
> javac -d classes -classpath jna-4.4.0.jar JavaNativeAccess.java
>
> cd classes
>
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
>
> java -classpath jna-4.4.0.jar:.
> com.enlightedinc.apps.where.utils.JavaNativeAccess

**now when I try to execute the code in this Ubuntu box, I get following error
Exceptionjava.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'randomNumber': ./librandomjna.so: undefined symbol: randomNumber**

- What can possibly go wrong ?
- Whats the difference between .dylib and .so file ?
- Why .dylib (mac osx) can resolve all function calls , whereas .so file (linux) fails to look up the function ?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Kaniska

Comment: In case you haven't yet decided whether to go with JNI or JNA, take a look here to get familiar with JNI: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/

Comment: BTW - what happens when you clone repo and do make run ? It should work out of the box.

Comment: JNI doesn't work for me as I don't have access to the c file in my actual project, I have only access to .o / .a / .so files

Comment: so I have tried JNA, now its working fine after generating .so file directly from .c code

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try following:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:.
```

Then, make sure your so file contains what you expect

```
nm librandomjna.so | grep rand
```

Comment: I had already set the > ld_library_path and yes the .so file was missing the symbol as it was generated from the .o file

Comment: now that I am generating .so file directly from .c file, its working fine, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

finally, I solved the problem by generating the .so file directly from the .c file

gcc -shared -fpic -o librandomjna.so randomjna.c

now .so file contains all the symbols.