# JNA loading Library with dependencies

Tags: java, c, shared-libraries, jna

I need to create an original .so library (C code) that uses another .so library. After creating my .so library I wrote a short test program code on C that invokes functions of my lib. It works, but when I compile this program I use that command:

```sh
gcc my_test.c -lm  -o my_test_program -lmy_lib -lother_lib -L
```

I need to use my library in Java code (JNA) but when I try to invoke functions from my lib I get this error:

> /usr/lib64/libmy_lib.so.0: undefined symbol

I think that means it has lost dependence of other_lib.

What can I do to add dependence in my_lib? Or other solutions?

Comment: Ensure the other library is in a location in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.  Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45378670/1161484)

Comment: Thank you! I got solution:

`gcc -g -shared -Wl,-soname,libmy_lib.so.0 -o libmy_lib.so.0.0 mylib.o -lc -lother_lib`

In compilation process I to add -lother_lib.